# Go Unicode combining characters (grapheme clusters) and MS Windows Console cmd.exe

Tags: go, unicode, windows-10, windows-console

In the following code, the `ü` is not the single Unicode character U+00FC but is a single grapheme cluster composed of two Unicode characters, the plain ASCII `u` U+0075 followed by the combining diaeresis U+0308.

```
fmt.Println("Jürgen ǅemal")
fmt.Println("Ju\u0308rgen \u01c5emel")
```

If I run it [in the go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/D0J2q2NdcGF), it works as expected.

If I run it in a MS Windows 10 "Command Prompt" window, it doesn't visually combine the combining character with the prior character.
However when I cut and paste the text into here it appears correctly:

```
C:\> ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.228]

C:\> test
Jürgen ǅemal
Jürgen ǅemel
```

On screen, in the "Command Prompt" window it looked more like:

```
Ju¨rgen ǅemel
```

Changing the code page (chcp) from 850 to 65001 made no difference. Changing fonts (Consolas, Courier etc) made no difference.

In the past I have experienced problems that were fundamentally because Microsoft require Windows programs to use a different API to output characters to STDOUT depending on whether STDOUT is attached to a console or to a file. I don't know if this is a different manifestation of the same issue.

Is there something I can do to make this Unicode grapheme-cluster  appear correctly?

Comment: The Windows console (conhost.exe) doesn't support combining codes. You'll have to first normalize to an [equivalent string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) that uses precomposed characters.

Comment: @eryksun: Thanks, that looks like an answer ...

Comment: If you haven't found this yet: you can use [golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm) to do the normalization (e.g. `norm.NFC.String("Jürgen ǅemal")`; not sure which one works for Windows).

Comment: @Peter: I was just playing around with that, thanks (it works). If one of you doesn't post an answer I'll put up a Community-Wiki answer citing you both.

Answer (score 3):

As [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) and [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603316/peter) commented,

- The Windows console (conhost.exe) doesn't support combining codes. You'll have to first normalize to an equivalent string that uses precomposed characters.
- you can use `golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm` to do the normalization (e.g. `norm.NFC.String("Jürgen ǅemal")`)

I tried this

```
s := "Ju\u0308rgen \u01c5emel"
fmt.Println(s)              // dieresis not combined with u by conhost.exe
s = norm.NFC.String(s)
fmt.Println(s)              // shows correctly
```

And the output looked like this

[image: Ju¨rgen ǅemel \n Jürgen ǅemel]

or, for the visually impaired with fabulously sophisticated screen readers - a bit like this:

```
Ju¨rgen ǅemel
Jürgen ǅemel
```

Note that Unicode has four different normalised forms but NFC is the most used on the Internet in web-pages and is also appropriate for this situation.

There are other methods in this package that may be more efficient or more useful

I read there are visual-characters in use which can only be represented in Unicode using combining characters. In other words for which there is no precomposed character. A more thorough approach would be needed to do something appropriate with those. Essentially the complications of Unicode (or perhaps more accurately of human languages and their typography) are almost without end. It sometimes seems that way to me.

References

- https://blog.golang.org/normalization
- https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/using-unicode-normalization-to-represent-strings

  > For example, several characters used in writing Lithuanian have double diacritics, as they have only decomposed forms. An example is lowercase U with macron and tilde ("ū̃", U+016b U+0303, where the first code point is a lowercase U with macron and the second is a combining acute accent).

Comment: If a character doesn't have a precomposed code unit, then the console can't display it. The console also can't display complex scripts, or mix half-width and full-width glyphs (at least not well), or support automatic fallback fonts (manually configured fallback is possible). These limitations are due to the console's use of legacy GDI functions dating back to its first release in Windows NT 3.1 (1993). The team that's responsible for the console at Microsoft has hinted that a redesign is planned based on DirectWrite.